# How to log Request and Errors on a PHP webservice without using any framework

Tags: php, error-logging

1. I am developing a PHP backend API server for a web application,
   which contains more than 50 PHP API's.
2. Now what I need is that I
   need to log all requests comes and errors occur to these API's.
3. I am not using any framework.
4. I have created my own code for logging
   the request which is given bellow.

// **************PHP API Request Log Code*****************

function log_data
    {

```
$req_dump = json_encode($_REQUEST);

$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$filename = str_replace(" ", "_", $_FILES['userfile']['name']);


$log  = "------------------------------------------------------------".PHP_EOL.
"UserIP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' - '.date("F j, Y, g:i a").PHP_EOL.
       "Request Data: ".$req_dump.PHP_EOL.
       "Request Method: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].PHP_EOL.
       "API URL: ".$actual_link.PHP_EOL.
       "File Name: ".$filename.PHP_EOL.
       "------------------------------------------------------------".PHP_EOL;
}


       // $fp = fopen('../api_logs/request.txt', 'a');
       // $fw = fwrite($fp, $log);
       // fclose($fp);
       $fp = file_put_contents( '../api_logs/request.log', $log, FILE_APPEND);

// **************PHP API Request Log Code*****************
```

5. Now what is the best method to log all API's request information and Error logs together into a file on the server itself?

Comment: if it has a single entry point ( such as index.php ) you can log requests there, also look these functions `register_shutdown_function`, `set_error_handler` and `set_exception_handler`

Comment: you can see some examples of how to use these on my github  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/EVO/Error/ErrorHandler.php  although this is part of a larger framework I am writing.

Answer (score 1):

Without any framework, you may use default php functions for [error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php):

- set_error_handler() for notices, warnings, deprecations etc. depending on your error reporting level.
- register_shutdown_function() for fatal errors
- set_exception_handler() for exceptions

Then you can store these information in text files or database.

Example for set_error_handler:

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    // do your custom error handling        
});
```

Example for register_shutdown_handler:

```
register_shutdown_function(function () {
    $error = error_get_last();
    // $error should be array containing 'message', 'file', 'line' etc...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [PHP error handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) to catch errors and warnings , as stated in the response of BenRoob. But pay attention, your code is vulnerable:

- To log poison : an attacker could inject code in your log, to exploit it with other types of vulnerability (like [LFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability)).
- [And Log injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Log_Injection)

To fix the first, you can make the log file not accessible from the user that run PHP ( for example, giving it only write access)
For the second, just escape all PHP_EOL from the user input.